# How to bind list from mvc action link view to controler?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, list, model-binding

I have following code but my Sizes list does not bind with controller.Any help would appriciate.

this my view model.

```
 public class ProductIqlMeasurementListingViewModel
    {
        public ProductIqlMeasurementListingViewModel()
        {
            Sizes = new List<SizeValueViewModel>();
        }

        public int StyleIlqMeasurementId { get; set; }
        public List<SizeValueViewModel> Sizes { get; set; }
        public double Tolerance { get; set; }
        public string MeasurementPointDescription { get; set; }
    }
```

this is controller.

```
public ActionResult EditMeasurement(int StyleIlqMeasurementId, List<SizeValueViewModel> Sizes)
{
    return View();
}
```

This is my view.

```
@model List<Codezync.ProductionMonitoring.ViewModels.ProductIqlMeasurementListingViewModel>
     <table class="table table-hover">
                            <tr>
                                <th></th>
                                <th>Measurement Points</th>
                                <th>Tolerance+/-</th>                                
                                @for (int i = 0; i < Model[0].Sizes.Count; i++)
                                {
                                    <th>@Model[0].Sizes[i].Code</th>
                                }

                            </tr>
                            @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
                            {
                                <tr>  
                                        @Html.HiddenFor(x => x[i].StyleIlqMeasurementId)
                                        @Html.HiddenFor(x => x[i].MeasurementPointDescription)
                                        @Html.HiddenFor(x => x[i].Sizes)                                  
                                    <td>@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "EditMeasurement", "Style",new { StyleIlqMeasurementId = Model[i].StyleIlqMeasurementId, Sizes = Model[i].Sizes }, new { @class = "ui-btn-right" })</td>                                    
                                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(x => x[i].MeasurementPointDescription)</td>
                                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(x => x[i].Tolerance)</td>                                        

                                    @for (int j = 0; j < Model[i].Sizes.Count; j++)
                                    {
                                        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(x => Model[i].Sizes[j].Value)</td>       
                                            @Html.HiddenFor(x => Model[i].Sizes[j].Value)

                                    }

                                </tr>
                            }

                        </table>
```

How can i get sizes list to my controller??Any help would appricate

Comment: Sizes is a collection. You should loop throught it and generate Hiddens for every one of the SizeValueViewModel items.

Comment: @AlejandroPérezFals if you can see Sizes is a list and it already looping in the view , isn't it?

Comment: sorry, i didnt saw that

Comment: Your generating a view for `List<ProductIqlMeasurementListingViewModel>` not `List<SizeValueViewModel>`. The parameter in your POST method needs to be `List<ProductIqlMeasurementListingViewModel> model`

Comment: Please note that the model-view-controller tag is for questions about the pattern. There is a specific tag for the ASP.NET-MVC implementation.

Comment: But what is the point of this - you do not have any editable form controls (and I assume that you do actually have a `<form>`?)